# rxjs return cached response based on condition

Tags: rxjs

I would like to create an observable which loads data from backend. However, I would like to tell him to really fetch it or take the results from cache.

```
  backendData$ = http.get(...).pipe(shareReplay(1));

  refresh$: Subject<{doBackendRequest: boolean}> = new Subject();
  rowData$ = this.refresh$.pipe(
                              tap(opts => console.log(opts.doBackendRequest)),
                              switchMap(() => {
                                if (opts.doBackendRequest) {
                                  // lets do a new request
                                  return backendData$;
                                } else {
                                  // somehow return cached results
                                  return CACHED_DATA;
                                }
                              })
```

The `rowData$` is subscribed by an async pipe `rowData$ | async`

Here is how I would like to call it:

```
this.refresh$.next({performBackendRequest: true});

this.refresh$.next({performBackendRequest: false});
```

The question now is how can I cache the http result? I tried to use `shareReplay(1)` but I can not find a working solution. Can you point me the direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how it might be implemented:

```js
 backendData$ = http.get(...);
 cachedData$ = backendData$.pipe(shareReplay(1));

 refresh$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
 rowData$ = this.refresh$
   .pipe(switchMap(refresh => refresh ? backendData$ : cachedData$))
```

Comment: perfect thanks. I encountered a new issue now: when the backend request is running and someone calls .next({performBackendRequest: false}) then the backend request is canceled due to switchMap

Comment: technically this is correct, for my use case its a problem :)